# Newtonian mechanics on an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

Consider a block of mass $m$ on a completely frictionless, fixed inclined plane inclined at an angle $\theta$ as shown here. Neglect any forces other than weight of the block.
[image]

So, as I have drawn here, a force $mgsin\theta$ acts on the block along the inclined surface.

**MY QUESTION:**

We know that the block will move down and along the surface i.e part of it's acceleration is towards the right. However, we already know that only the weight $mg$ is acting on the block and that has no horizontal component. So, what causes this part - horizontal reaction that we observe? What is the force I'm missing here? Illustrating my question here..
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)

Comment: No, it's not there. Break mg into components which are parallel and perpendicular to the incline. They replace mg conceptually.  mg is real, the components are conceptual replacements for mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you neglecting any force on the block other than its weight?
Isn't it the normal reaction of wedge on the block that has a horizontal component, giving it an acceleration in that direction?

Comment: Even that doesn't make sense. First of all, the normal reaction is the 'reaction' of the surface to the component of the blocks weight perpendicular to the surface. If you say that the horizontal acceleration is provided by the horizontal component of the normal force, that would be just as good as my assertion since that too would imply that the block's weight has a component in a perpendicular direction

Comment: How is that a reason to neglect it? It's still a force on the object.

Comment: You can't  take the component of the component. If you really want to do that, it's possible to take the component on the other side, as mgcosAsinA acting towards the left. So if you really want to consider this force, consider that there is also an opposite force giving it the exact same acceleration on the other side which cancels it out. However, that's not a good explanation or the right method.

Comment: Yeah. So the acceleration is because of the normal force. But magnitude wise it's same as the component of the component of the weight. Right?

Comment: Its the same as $mg \cos \theta$

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in calculation. Yeah, N=mgcosA so NsinA will technically have the same magnitude. But this doesn't mean that the force mgcosAsinA actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your second digram in your question is $\textbf{wrong}$. There is no force $F=mg\sin \theta\cos \theta$ for an object on an inclined plane.

> However, we already know that only the weight $mg$ is acting on the block and that has no horizontal component

I think you are going wrong with this statement that you made in your question. The $mg$ force on an inclined plane is correct the way you have drawn it, and you can resolving this force in two directions, either parallel or perpendicular to the surface of the plane. And more importantly the weight is not the $\textbf{only}$ force on the block, there is also a normal force. [image: Forces on an inclined plane]

So really, the normal force has a horizontal component that is giving it an acceleration along the inclined plane.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we do the force balances in the horizontal and vertical directions rather than in the directions parallel and perpendicular to the incline.  In this case, the vertical component of the normal force is $N\cos{\theta}$ and the horizontal component is $N\sin{\theta}$.  And, if a is the component of acceleration tangent to the plane, then the vertical component of acceleration is $a\sin{\theta}$ and the horizontal component is $a\cos{\theta}$.  So, the force balances in the vertical and horizontal directions are:
$$mg-N\cos{\theta}=ma\sin{\theta}\tag{vertical}$$
$$N\sin{\theta}=ma\cos{\theta}\tag{horizontal}$$
If we multiply the vertical equation by $\sin{\theta}$ and the horizontal equation by $\cos{\theta}$, and add, we obtain:$$mg\sin{\theta}=ma$$ or$$a=g\sin{\theta}$$If we multiply the horizontal equation by $\sin{\theta}$ and the vertical equation by $\cos{\theta}$ and subtract, we obtain$$N=mg\cos{\theta}$$
From the horizontal equation, it is seen that it is the normal force that is causing the horizontal acceleration.